# Explaining Combinations With Repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to understand Combinations with repetetions. I looked up the internet but all of them I saw used slots method to explain. Is there other, better way to explain? Thank You.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Are you looking for stars and bars or the formula given for $\dbinom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ ?

Comment: If there is something you don't understand about the explanations you've seen, you might have better luck asking specifically about the things you don't understand. As is, there's no guarantee that any explanation you get will be any better than the ones you've seen and didn't like.